# flutter : implementing json as list returns a null list

Tags: mysql, json, flutter

hello I'm making a new flutter app and I'm new to flutter , I'm using a mysql database and iam getting the response as json .
Here is my formatted json response :

**JsonResponse**

```
{
   "folders":[
      {
         "id":2107,
         "name":"Labs ",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-09-30 03:00:39",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2108,
         "name":"L1",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-09-30 03:00:45",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2130,
         "name":"L2",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-02
02:39:11",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2175,
         "name":"L3",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-07 03:43:15",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2202,
         "name":"L4",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-09 02:08:10",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2227,
         "name":"\u0645\u0631\u0627\u062c\u0639\u0627\u062a
",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-11 05:15:43",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2242,
         "name":"L5",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-14 03:45:24",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2257,
         "name":"L6",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-16
06:23:41",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2269,
         "name":"L7",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-21 03:39:12",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2309,
         "name":"L8",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-23 05:14:48",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2310,
         "name":"L8",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-23
05:14:51",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2346,
         "name":"L9",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-28 04:22:24",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2370,
         "name":"L10",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-10-30 03:02:00",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2446,
         "name":"L11",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-12
06:28:13",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2462,
         "name":"\u062a\u0628\u064a\u0636\u0627\u062a",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-13 08:39:00",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2464,
         "name":"L12",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-13
08:40:55",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2488,
         "name":"L13",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-18 06:09:11",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2490,
         "name":"L14",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-18 06:38:59",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2491,
         "name":"L15",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-18
06:45:57",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2497,
         "name":"\u062a\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0635\u0627\u062a",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":1,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-19 04:24:49",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2509,
         "name":"L16",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-20
09:56:04",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2522,
         "name":"L17",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-25 06:38:27",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2542,
         "name":"L18",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-27 12:19:12",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2552,
         "name":"Protein
Lab",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-27 16:32:27",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2562,
         "name":"Chromatography ",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-11-30 15:24:24",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2576,
         "name":"L19",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-02
02:05:29",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2580,
         "name":"L20",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-02 08:23:48",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2592,
         "name":"21",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-03 06:27:24",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2600,
         "name":"L22",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-04
06:22:46",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2614,
         "name":"L23",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-04 10:03:00",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2640,
         "name":"L24",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-08 06:53:11",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2644,
         "name":"L25",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-09
05:33:07",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2649,
         "name":"L26",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-09 07:58:42",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      },
      {
         "id":2711,
         "name":"\u0623\u0633\u0626\u0644\u0629",
         "img":null,
         "haschild":0,
         "parentid":1955,
         "createdate":"2019-12-19
05:18:11",
         "inarchive":0,
         "active":1
      }
   ],
   "files":[
      {
         "id":4542,
         "name":"Ch2-part1.m4a 27.52MB",
         "img":null,
         "uploader":"Aws",
         "url":"http:\/\/msc-mu.com\/..\/uploaded\/031020190Ch2-part1.m4a",
         "createdate":"2019-10-03 09:53:39",
         "approved":1,
         "active":1
      }
   ]
}
```

And whenever I try to implement the list of folders and files it says that there is nothing inside the list and its null
here is my code :
**fellow.dart**

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final YearsMain value;

  SecondScreen({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  Future<List<Folders>> getData() async {
    List<Folders> list;
    String link =
        "http://msc-mu.com/api_verfication.php";
    var res = await http.post(link,body: {
      'flag':'selectfellowsubjects',
      'year':widget.value.id
    });
    print(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);
      var rest = data["folders"] as List;
      print(rest);
      list = rest.map<Folders>((json) => Folders.fromJson(json)).toList();
    }
    print("List Size: ${list.length}");
    return list;
    }

  Widget listViewWidget(List<Folders> article) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  '${article[position].name}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                onTap: () => _onTapItem(context, article[position]),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  void _onTapItem(BuildContext context, Folders folders) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => DownloadPage()));
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print(widget.value.id);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  Center(
        child: new FutureBuilder<List<Folders>>(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List fellow = snapshot.data;
              return listViewWidget(fellow);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the **output** :

```
I/flutter (21630): {"folders":[],"files":[]}
I/flutter (21630): []
I/flutter (21630): List Size: 0
```

any help ?

Comment: Hi!  You can try data["folders"].forEach((v) {
          list .add(Folders.fromJson(v));
        });

Comment: `  Future<List<Folders>> getData() async {
    List<Folders> list;
    String link =
        "http://msc-mu.com/api_verfication.php";
    var res = await http.post(link,body: {
      'flag':'selectfellowsubjects',
      'year':widget.value.id
    });
    print(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);
      var rest = data["folders"].forEach((v) { list .add(Folders.fromJson(v)); });
      print(rest);
      list = rest.map<Folders>((json) => Folders.fromJson(json)).toList();
    }
    return list;
    }`

Comment: if you mean like this , it did not work , same thing returning lists as null

Comment: delete line list = rest.map<Folders>((json) => Folders.fromJson(json)).toList();

Comment: can you write the full code of function in an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<List<Folders>> getData() async {
    List<Folders> list= <Folders>[];
    String link = "msc-mu.com/api_verfication.php";
    try {
      var res = await http.post(link,
          body: {'flag': 'selectfellowsubjects', 'year': widget.value.id});
      print(res.body);
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(res.body);
        var rest = data["folders"].forEach((v) {
          list.add(Folders.fromJson(v));
        });
        print(rest);
      }
      return list;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('$e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: type<ArugmentError> is not a subtype of type<String>

Comment: You can try again  and give me more detail !

Comment: can we reach out on discord

Comment: ill put it as a answer put i need the help plz ....

Comment: Sorry! This is my fault you just change debugPrint(e) to debugPrint('$e').

Comment: sorry for wasting your time , ive tried the old function that is in the post and changed a couple of things in the db data and it worked but it shows something that is quit different

Comment: take a look at the screenshot :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OvpOTL3cFt3H3XFPnJrq6mFNVnC2tWFR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I very fun to help you. You can try again my code :)).

Comment: I/flutter (26628): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (26628): Receiver: null
I/flutter (26628): Tried calling: []("id")

Comment: it gets the list in the debug put i have started to thing that the problem right knwo is in the call back in the widget do u agree ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 class FilesAndFoldersModel {
  List<Folders> folders;
  List<Files> files;

  FilesAndFoldersModel({this.folders, this.files});

  FilesAndFoldersModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['folders'] != null) {
      folders = new List<Folders>();
      json['folders'].forEach((v) {
        folders.add(new Folders.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['files'] != null) {
      files = new List<Files>();
      json['files'].forEach((v) {
        files.add(new Files.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.folders != null) {
      data['folders'] = this.folders.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.files != null) {
      data['files'] = this.files.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Folders {
  int id;
  String name;
  Null img;
  int haschild;
  int parentid;
  String createdate;
  int inarchive;
  int active;

  Folders(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.img,
      this.haschild,
      this.parentid,
      this.createdate,
      this.inarchive,
      this.active});

  Folders.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    img = json['img'];
    haschild = json['haschild'];
    parentid = json['parentid'];
    createdate = json['createdate'];
    inarchive = json['inarchive'];
    active = json['active'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['img'] = this.img;
    data['haschild'] = this.haschild;
    data['parentid'] = this.parentid;
    data['createdate'] = this.createdate;
    data['inarchive'] = this.inarchive;
    data['active'] = this.active;
    return data;
  }
}

class Files {
  int id;
  String name;
  Null img;
  String uploader;
  String url;
  String createdate;
  int approved;
  int active;

  Files(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.img,
      this.uploader,
      this.url,
      this.createdate,
      this.approved,
      this.active});

  Files.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    img = json['img'];
    uploader = json['uploader'];
    url = json['url'];
    createdate = json['createdate'];
    approved = json['approved'];
    active = json['active'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['img'] = this.img;
    data['uploader'] = this.uploader;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['createdate'] = this.createdate;
    data['approved'] = this.approved;
    data['active'] = this.active;
    return data;
  }
}
```

After making such model you should then do null check to check if each value is having a value.

Comment: can you please tell me what to do next ? or update your answer to implement it in the ui and its function ?

Comment: You can now access the model by just making the instance of it. Once the model is made, I'll suggest you make a call the model and do a null check on it.